# run growlnotify over ssh

Tags: ssh, growl

I am trying to run growl notify over ssh like so
    ssh andrew@192.168.1.8 "growlnotify -m test"
is run I get 
    bash: growlnotify command not found
however running it straight from the mac it runs fine
am I missing something simple or is there a really complex reason this won't work?
ps. ssh keys are enabled in both directions

edit: I logged into the mac from a remote machine over ssh and tried to run it and it ran fine  so it seems to just affect the one line login and run way and DrC tried that cated the .profile to .bashrc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you use the complete path to growlnotify?

```
ssh andrew@192.168.1.8 "/usr/local/bin/growlnotify -m test"
```

Comment: it works thank you very much knew it had to be something really stupidly simple like that

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the code in your ~/.bashrc sets your path the same as .profile or .bash_profile.   If it doesn't exist and the latter file doesn't produce any spurious output, then you could link them.

I'm being a bit vague as I don't recall exactly which is used on each mac version.  In 10.8, my init code was in .profile and .bashrc is linked to that.